# IIS 7.0 / Windows Server 2008 - DLL not found in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008

I try to run an ASPX page hosted on a Windows Server 2008 x86 through IIS 7.0, with .NET 4.0. I added an application, `app1`, to the `Default Web Site` of IIS, mapped to dir `C:\toto\app1` which contains the `Web.config` file.
The error I have is:

*Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or one of its dependencies*, etc

and `xxx.dll` is a .NET DLL that wraps native C++ DLLs (**they** are the dependencies that fail to be loaded), all of them are located in `C:\toto\app1\bin`. I tried to modify the PATH env variable so that it contained the `bin` directory (yes, I know it's bad :-) ), but this did not work anyway.

I guess there should be something at IIS application level, but I could not see what... Could you please help ?

Many thanks !

EDIT: copying the native DLLs in `C:\windows\system32` actually works, but it's not a pleasant solution at all...

Comment: Which Path do you have in reference in your DLL solution?

Comment: Do you mean the reference path (the external DLL is in the Reference pseudo folder of my VS 2010 project) ? If so, it's '..\..\..\LIB\IRIS'. I tried to create the same relative path and add the external lib inside (considering the root of the aplication is the dir where the Web.config resides), but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally managed to make it work by copying the DLLs into `windows\system32` directory (no idea why it did not wotk the 1st time, probably an error of mine...). The `application\bin` folders don't work, neither does the change of the `PATH` variable.

If anyone knows a better solution (I don't find this one brilliant at all, that can cause DLLs collision and so on), I'd be glad to hear it !

Comment: Copying dlls into the windows\system32 directory is extremely bad form.  There is no reason your application should ever put files there.   That directory is for MS libraries only and even they shun it for a number of their applications.  Instead you should either have all of the necessary assemblies in your bin folder OR GAC them.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, this isnt really a solution given the security and overall systems ramifications. Sounds like the 3rd party lib you are using is doing some very odd pathing mechanism that's causing it to be loaded by the w3wp process (which runs in system32) vs in the context of the app.  Have you tried GACing the library?  that would at least save the system32 prob.

Comment: I know, I know, it's bad, that's what I already said ! But no other way to make it **work** for now, so unless I'm told something better... Yes, I'm desperate ! By the way, GAC is only for .NET DLLs registration, so impossible to register my native DLL this way.

Comment: Native libraries must be placed in Windows\system32, as .NET does not look for them in bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

If its not GACd (which it doesn't appear to be), the simple answer is:

You need the external DLL to be in the bin\ directory of the application.

If you have it as a reference in VS2010, select it, go to properties, and set the CopyLocal value to True.  Rebuild the application.  This should cause that DLL to copy out to the bin and your app can reference without any other work.

Comment: Ah, I think I was not precise enough: both my VS2010 DLL and the external one are in the `bin` directory.

Comment: Yes, no problem in local, the problem comes up when deploying on the remote MS Server 2008.

Comment: If possible, can you post the FULL text of the ASP.NET error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job.
Do this on the server. 
Undo all the things you've done before doing this. 
Go to START->RUN and type `cmd` then run the following command `regsvr32 "C:\yourfolder\idrskrn_net14.dll"` with the " included.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this doesn't work: my external DLL is not a COM DLL (for which indeed registration is made via `regsvr32`) but a **native** DLL: `regsvr32` fals in this case (saying "no DllserverRegister entry point found").

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. The dll are in the webapp/bin directory but aren't loaded. I managed to put them in the inetpub/bin and there it runs fine. However there must be a behaviour that allows loading module in the webapp bin directory. Don't know how to setup this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  If I browse the website locally on the server it works fine but when I browse it across the internet via the domain name it cannot find the DLL's that are in the bin folder of the site...